# Monthly and Annual Compound Interest in SAS using DO Loop

Tags: sas

I am studying SAS on my own. I have no one to refer to so I just wanted to check if my code is correct.

**In a fixed term deposit of 25 years calculate the total amount at the end of
term with initial amount of $5,00,000 and annual interest rate of 7 %  */
 1) Compounded Annually 
 2) Compounded Monthly.Show the amount at monthly level**

```
My Code:
data deposit;
amount = 500000;
rate = 0.07;
do year = 1 to 25;
amount + earned;
earned + (amount*0.07);
principal = amount + earned;
output;
end;
run;
```

For the second question compounded monthly

```
data deposit1;
rate = 0.006;
amount1 = 500000;
do year = 1 to 25;
do month = 1 to 12;
earned1 + (earned1 + amount1)*0.006;
amount1 + earned1;
output;
end;
end;
run;
```

Pasting the Screenshots of Solution 1 and Solution 2
[image: Problem 1 Result]
[image: Problem 2 Result]

I am confused because when I compound annually and monthly both have different results at the end of a particular year.

Please suggest if anything is wrong in my code. Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: Why did you change the interest rate from 7% in the annual calculations to 6% in the monthly calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are double-counting your earned1 variable in the monthly compounding code.

```
earned1 + (earned1 + amount1)*0.006;
amount1 + earned1;
```

Should be:

```
earned1 = amount1*0.07**(1/12);
amount1 + earned1;
```

Note also you will not want to round the interest rate.

Comment: Thank you Craig but one question will the compound interest monthly and CI annual will always differ as they have different values. Because Compound Interest is always applied on the total which has the amount and the interest unlike in case of Simple interest where the value is applied on only the amount. So if we see here neither of the scenario fulfill the criteria for the monthly compound interest calculation. Please guide.

Comment: Sorry, I just made an edit to fix an error in the first line of the monthly code - should be `earned1 = amount1*0.07**(1/12);`and not `earned1 + amount1*0.07**(1/12);`

Comment: Monthly compounding is going to give you a different result than annual compounding.

Comment: Many thanks Craig for helping out ! Really grateful !